# How can I label points in ggplot2 automatically without overlapping labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Preventing labels at the end of the lines from overlapping is a particular challenge for this data because I want the same code to work with data that varies a fair bit.  In the example below some of the labels would need to be far from the point they are labeling to make room.  I'm ok with that, and I just want to know if there is a way to do it programmatically because I can't be customizing the code for each dataset I need to apply it to.  Thanks!

I'm also struggling to format the labels: I rounded them to the nearest percent but despite playing with  `sprintf` I can't figure out how to get rid of the decimal point and trailing zero.

[image: lineplot]

My data can be recreated with this:

```
mydf <- 
structure(list(date = structure(c(15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 
                                           15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 
                                           15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 
                                           15595, 15596, 15597, 15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 
                                           15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 
                                           15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 
                                           15597, 15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 
                                           15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 
                                           15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 15597, 15573, 
                                           15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 
                                           15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 
                                           15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 15597, 15573, 15574, 15575, 
                                           15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 
                                           15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 
                                           15594, 15595, 15596, 15597, 15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 
                                           15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 
                                           15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 
                                           15596, 15597, 15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 
                                           15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 
                                           15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 15597, 
                                           15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 
                                           15582, 15583, 15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 
                                           15591, 15592, 15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 15597, 15573, 15574, 
                                           15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 15582, 15583, 
                                           15584, 15585, 15586, 15587, 15588, 15589, 15590, 15591, 15592, 
                                           15593, 15594, 15595, 15596, 15597), class = "Date"), outcome = c(0.0514, 
                                                                                                            0.0555, 0.0611, 0.0646, 0.0565, 0.055, 0.0588, 0.0504, 0.0585, 
                                                                                                            0.0576, 0.0546, 0.0553, 0.0123, 0.0155, 0.0066, 0.0105, 0.0179, 
                                                                                                            0.0052, 0.0057, 0.007, 0.0094, 0.0127, 0.0122, 0.0089, 0.0097, 
                                                                                                            0.0305, 0.0248, 0.033, 0.037, 0.0305, 0.0334, 0.0346, 0.0356, 
                                                                                                            0.034, 0.0317, 0.0351, 0.034, 0.0091, 0.0026, 0.0151, 0.0152, 
                                                                                                            0.0145, 0.006, 0.0052, 0.0082, 0.0122, 0.017, 0.008, 0.0136, 
                                                                                                            0.0114, 0.0068, 0.0042, 0.0085, 0.0134, 0.0091, 0.0127, 0.0082, 
                                                                                                            0.0154, 0.0088, 0.0102, 0.0127, 0.0168, 0.0057, 0.0106, 0.0107, 
                                                                                                            0.0076, 0.006, 0.0116, 0.0116, 0.0107, 0.0087, 0.0046, 0.0126, 
                                                                                                            0.005, 0.0074, 0.0259, 0.0174, 0.0172, 0.0182, 0.028, 0.0238, 
                                                                                                            0.0269, 0.0312, 0.0213, 0.0334, 0.0247, 0.0232, 0.0261, 0.0229, 
                                                                                                            0.0183, 0.0238, 0.0221, 0.016, 0.0232, 0.0177, 0.0251, 0.0202, 
                                                                                                            0.0232, 0.0153, 0.0237, 0.0511, 0.0578, 0.0547, 0.0536, 0.0202, 
                                                                                                            0.014, 0.007, 0.0126, 0.0145, 0.015, 0.0117, 0.0169, 0.0136, 
                                                                                                            0.0128, 0.0127, 0.0138, 0.0092, 0.0094, 0.0106, 0.0098, 0.0093, 
                                                                                                            0.0141, 0.0063, 0.0104, 0.0183, 0.0259, 0.0195, 0.0289, 0.0247, 
                                                                                                            0.027, 0.0264, 0.0281, 0.023, 0.0175, 0.0247, 0.0166, 0.0224, 
                                                                                                            0.0196, 0.0177, 0.0248, 0.0236, 0.0205, 0.0245, 0.0225, 0.019, 
                                                                                                            0.0167, 0.0154, 0.0204, 0.0244, 0.0235, 0.0114, 0.0108, 0.0136, 
                                                                                                            0.0064, 0.0088, 0.0161, 0.0143, 0.009, 0.0107, 0.0031, 0.0012, 
                                                                                                            0.0108, 0.0146, 0.0044, 0.0058, 0.0129, 0.006, 0.0157, 0.0107, 
                                                                                                            0.0105, 0.0093, 0.0077, 0.0078, 0.0105, 0.0067, 0.0055, 0.0137, 
                                                                                                            0.0108, 0.021, 0.0081, 0.0149, 0.0071, 0.0106, 0.0048, 0.0073, 
                                                                                                            0.0122, 0.0059, 0.0115, 0.0103, 0.0093, 0.0037, 0.0065, 0.0038, 
                                                                                                            0.0129, 0.008, 0.0045, 0.0098, 0.0047, 0.0123, 0.0088, 0.1243, 
                                                                                                            0.1209, 0.1196, 0.1311, 0.1193, 0.1269, 0.1313, 0.1332, 0.1244, 
                                                                                                            0.1308, 0.1229, 0.1273, 0.1276, 0.115, 0.1075, 0.1119, 0.1163, 
                                                                                                            0.1172, 0.112, 0.1125, 0.1184, 0.1071, 0.107, 0.1081, 0.1126), 
                        trial = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                  "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                  "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                  "B", "B", "B", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
                                  "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
                                  "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                  "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                  "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
                                  "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
                                  "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
                                  "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
                                  "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
                                  "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
                                  "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "D", "D", "D", 
                                  "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                  "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", 
                                  "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                  "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), .Names = c("date", 
                                                                                                      "outcome", "trial"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(94L, 
                                                                                                                                                               95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
                                                                                                                                                               106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
                                                                                                                                                               117L, 118L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 
                                                                                                                                                               365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 
                                                                                                                                                               376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 618L, 619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 
                                                                                                                                                               624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 
                                                                                                                                                               635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 880L, 881L, 882L, 
                                                                                                                                                               883L, 884L, 885L, 886L, 887L, 888L, 889L, 890L, 891L, 892L, 893L, 
                                                                                                                                                               894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1142L, 1143L, 1144L, 1145L, 1146L, 1147L, 1148L, 1149L, 1150L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1151L, 1152L, 1153L, 1154L, 1155L, 1156L, 1157L, 1158L, 1159L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1160L, 1161L, 1162L, 1163L, 1164L, 1165L, 1166L, 1404L, 1405L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1406L, 1407L, 1408L, 1409L, 1410L, 1411L, 1412L, 1413L, 1414L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1415L, 1416L, 1417L, 1418L, 1419L, 1420L, 1421L, 1422L, 1423L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1424L, 1425L, 1426L, 1427L, 1428L, 1666L, 1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1675L, 1676L, 1677L, 1678L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1679L, 1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 1684L, 1685L, 1686L, 1687L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1688L, 1689L, 1690L, 1928L, 1929L, 1930L, 1931L, 1932L, 1933L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1934L, 1935L, 1936L, 1937L, 1938L, 1939L, 1940L, 1941L, 1942L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1943L, 1944L, 1945L, 1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 1949L, 1950L, 1951L, 
                                                                                                                                                               1952L, 2190L, 2191L, 2192L, 2193L, 2194L, 2195L, 2196L, 2197L, 
                                                                                                                                                               2198L, 2199L, 2200L, 2201L, 2202L, 2203L, 2204L, 2205L, 2206L, 
                                                                                                                                                               2207L, 2208L, 2209L, 2210L, 2211L, 2212L, 2213L, 2214L))
```

Here is my code to create the graph

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x=date, y=outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = trial, color = trial, linetype = trial), data = mydf, size=0.75) +
  geom_text(data = mydf[mydf$date==max(mydf$date),], aes(x = date + (0.003 * nrow(mydf)), y = outcome, label = sprintf("%0.1f%%",   round(outcome, 2) * 100)), size = 4, colour = "grey50") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))
```

Comment: You might try the `directlabels` package, which is designed to avoid overlapping labels.  I'm not sure how it would perform in your case however.  But worth a look.

Comment: Do you have to scale the Y axis between 0 and 1? 0 and 0.25 might help in this situation?

Comment: @Joran, thanks for the link, hopefully my more constrained labeling problem will lead to answers not given on that related question.  Simon, yes a big part of the problem is that I must show all the possible values for the Y-axis... the intention is to make hundreds of comparable graphs.  Bryan: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Try [ggrepel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel) with `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`